# How copy the content of CK-editor to the clipboard like ctrl+C?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I have a ck-editor in my web page. I need to have a button to copy the content of the editor without html content but with the new lines.
When I write into the editor:
[image: Editor content]

And select all and do ctrl+C it copy with the new lines. But if I use the custom coppy button, it copies the content without the new lines. The code of the button is:

```
$('#copyToCB').on('click', function (){
      var html = CKEDITOR.instances.printEditor.getData();
      var dom = document.createElement("DIV");
      dom.innerHTML = html;
      var plain_text = (dom.textContent || dom.innerText);

      $("#magicInput").val(plain_text);
});

new Clipboard('#copyToCB');
```

I want that it copies:

hello

hello

But it now copies:
hellohello

Thank you!!